# I can't seem to point the correct nameserver to my VPS

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, vps, nameserver, devops

I'm hosting my domain on Namecheap and im trying to point my nameservers to connect to my VPS using Webuzo (on Hostinger)

it shows this error on my VPS on Webuzo:

" This system does not control DNS for the ****.hstgr.cloud domain. You can add the suggested dkim record locally. However, this server is not the authoritative nameserver. If you add this record, this change will not be effective . Contact the person responsible for the any2.hostinger.com and any1.hostinger.com nameservers and request that they update the dkim record with the following dkim. "
[Webuzo email deliverability screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMuws.png)

I put an A record of the IP address of my server but for some reason it's still showing this error.

All records are setup properly on https://dnschecker.org/ .

Here are my DNS records on namecheap:
[dns screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvYaY.png)
[dns screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYva2.png)
But still having problems with email deliverability as well as website up-time.

The domain is scoleinn.com

Comment: Do you want use the hostinger DNS nameservers, or do you want run your own using BIND or PowerDNS

Answer (score 0):

According to nslookup,

```
Non-authoritative answer:
scoleinn.com
        primary name server = dns1.registrar-servers.com
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.registrar-servers.com
        serial  = 1707483271
        refresh = 43200 (12 hours)
        retry   = 3600 (1 hour)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 3601 (1 hour 1 sec)

scoleinn.com    nameserver = dns1.registrar-servers.com
scoleinn.com    nameserver = dns2.registrar-servers.com
```

So in fact, you would have to set your DKIM records in the zone file on `registrar-servers.com`, which is where the screen shots of your DNS settings appear to be.

Comment: how can i do that ?

Comment: You sent screen shots of your DNS records. You would go back to that page and add the TXT records there that you need for DKIM. Right down at the bottom of that image I see `Add new record`; I would think it kind of obvious how you'd add a new TXT record.

Comment: I've already added my DKIM record.

Comment: You've put in a stub DMARC record `v=DMARC1; p=none;` which would seem to be insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

At namecheap you need to change it to CustomDNS as described here
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/767/10/how-to-change-dns-for-a-domain/

There you need to put in the hostinger nameservers

```
ns1.dns-parking.com
ns2.dns-parking.com
```

Comment: i tried to do that before but if you have a look at my domain on https://intodns.com/scoleinn.com there is a bunch of errors

Comment: I think it's best to move this to the chat so we can help you a bit more interactively https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151410/i-cant-seem-to-point-the-correct-nameserver-to-my-vps